# Firebase phone sign-in, where to put firebase recaptcha code?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

### Edit:

To my knowledge this won't actually work with react doing it this way since it is referencing a container with the id of `recaptcha-container` from the window object. The reason being because react uses the bundle js script to load its rendered data. This is why no matter where I put this I keep getting the: `reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner elements!`

So it may be better if I ask how to implement this in for React rather than where to put this bit of code. If enough people can confirm this I will edit the title as well.

### End of Edit

This may be a general question , but I have not found anything on how to use the phone sign in with firebase and react. I have no clue where to put this bit of code into my react project (In a component, inside the root index.js, etc...) Please let me know if I need to include or ask this question differently so I can change it. Here is the code that I am struggling with as far as location goes:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
  'size': 'normal',
  'callback': function(response) {
    // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
    // ...
  },
  'expired-callback': function() {
    // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
    // ...
  }
});
```

I tried putting this inside a component inside the `componentWillMount()` and nothing at all happened. I also tried putting this in my root index.js above the `reactDOM.render` bit and got something like:

`reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner elements!`

Again please let me know what I can add to this or if I can improve my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. The reason why it did not work in `componentWillMount` is because the container id you gave is not present in the dom yet. (*will mount*)
2. RecaptchaVerifier requires an empty div to be present for authentication. When you put the function inside render, it gets called again when the div will not be empty.

Now coming to the solution,

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(this.recaptcha, {
    'size': 'normal',
    'callback': function (response) {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      // ...
    },
    'expired-callback': function () {
      // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
      // ...
    }
 });
 window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function (widgetId) {
   window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
 });
}
```

and in the HTML,

```
<div ref={(ref)=>this.recaptcha=ref}></div>
```

Instead of providing the id of the recaptcha div, we provide the [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) of the DOM element (as is the practice in the React world), you can see the [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier) of `RecaptchaVerifier` for more information.

Comment: Sorry for such a delay in response I have not been at a computer, I will try this now , but it looks like it should work, if it does I will accept the answer

Comment: Everything worked except I think you need to add `window` in front of the `recaptchaVerifier.render()` bit other wise it did not work for me. Ill make the edit and accept the answer.

Comment: Anything on the window is default enabled (Think fetch api or setTimeout), but adding `window` is a good practice.

Comment: Okay! For some reason recaptcahVerifier kept showing up as undefined until I added window not sure why

Comment: we add this but there another error  " 
TypeError: _base__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor "

Comment: RecaptchaVerifier requires an empty div Resolve my issue, thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Or, with `React.useRef` hook and TypeScript:

```
import React, {
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/firestore';

export const LoginScreen: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const app: app.app.App | null = app.initializeApp();
  const captchaRef = React.useRef(null);

  const OnPressLogin = async(phone: string) => {
    this.auth ? .signInWithPhoneNumber(
      phone,
      new app.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(captchaRef.current, {
        size: 'invisible',
        callback: (response: any) => {
          console.info('Invisible Captcha', response);
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          onCaptcha();
        },
      }),
    );
  };

  return ( <>
        <div id="recaptcha-container" ref={captchaRef}></div>
        <LoginForm disabled={isBusy} onSubmit={OnPressLogin} />
  );
};
```